# .r vs r in scala regex

Tags: regex, scala

I am reading Scala codes and found the following:

```
  val TimeRegex = """^([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$""".r

  val FilePattern = """^.*/date=(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)/([^/]+)(?:\.dat)?\.gz$"""r
```

what are the difference between `r` and `.r` at the end of regular expressions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result would be the same - both would call `StringLike`'s `r` method.

The latter uses Scala's "Postfix" notation, see [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html). The difference is only in style (compiler would de-sugar the latter into the former), but notice that postfix notation is usually discouraged. From the documentation:

> This style is unsafe, and should not be used

Comment: Indeed, it emits the feature warning, and in 2.13 it will require explicit enablement. It's like postfix is another powerful figure who has fallen in the wake of #MeToo.